# gatt.writeDescriptor() returns onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing app that needs to connect with A&D BP BLE device,I Can able to connect ,disconnect from BLE device,But can't able to get reading ,added full logs here,Please let me know how to proceed further,

```
09-14 11:03:06.624: D/BluetoothAdapter(9124): startLeScan(): null
09-14 11:03:06.630: D/BluetoothLeScanner(9124): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
09-14 11:03:30.510: D/BluetoothAdapter(9124): stopLeScan()
09-14 11:03:30.523: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): connect() - device: D0:5F:B8:03:79:70, auto: false
09-14 11:03:30.523: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): registerApp()
09-14 11:03:30.523: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): registerApp() - UUID=d0c559ba-1076-4b59-87d3-4547c46810b1
09-14 11:03:30.525: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
09-14 11:03:30.528: D/BleService(9124): Trying to create a new connection.
09-14 11:03:30.588: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=D0:5F:B8:03:79:70
09-14 11:03:30.588: V/On broadcast Updated.(9124): Entered..com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED
09-14 11:03:30.598: I/BleService(9124): Connected to GATT server.
09-14 11:03:30.598: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): discoverServices() - device: D0:5F:B8:03:79:70
09-14 11:03:30.605: I/BleService(9124): Attempting to start service discovery:true
09-14 11:03:30.607: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): onSearchComplete() = Device=D0:5F:B8:03:79:70 Status=0
09-14 11:03:30.607: D/BleService(9124): onServicesDiscoverd
09-14 11:03:30.607: V/BleService(9124): on service discovered Status 0=0
09-14 11:03:30.607: D/BleService(9124):   0
09-14 11:03:30.622: D/MainAct(9124):   com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED
09-14 11:03:30.627: D/BloodPressureMeasurement(9124): setIndication
09-14 11:03:30.627: D/BloodPressureMeasurement(9124): Service Not Null
09-14 11:03:30.627: D/BloodPressureMeasurement(9124): Characteristic Not Null
09-14 11:03:30.627: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
09-14 11:03:30.637: D/BloodPressureMeasurement(9124): Characteristic Status isSuccess : true
09-14 11:03:30.637: D/BloodPressureMeasurement(9124): make descriptor  enable : true
09-14 11:04:00.574: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=5 device=D0:5F:B8:03:79:70
09-14 11:04:00.574: I/BleService(9124): Disconnected from GATT server.
09-14 11:04:00.574: V/On broadcast Updated.(9124): Entered..com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED
09-14 11:04:00.607: D/MainAct(9124):   com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED
```

---

After Calling **gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);**app is returning below logs

```
   09-14 11:04:00.574: D/BluetoothGatt(9124): onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=5 device=D0:5F:B8:03:79:70
    09-14 11:04:00.574: I/BleService(9124): Disconnected from GATT server.
```

Comment: It seems you never get a write response from the peripheral and the local GATT implementation therefore times out and disconnects the device. You can check the "Bluetooth HCI snoop log" whether that is what happens.